# Does Virtual Box supports 64 bit of Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14 as a guest OS using Virtual Box. The host is Windows 8.1.

Virtualization is enabled. Still the Virtual Box shows only the 32-bit option for installing Ubuntu (see Virtual Box screenshot).

Processor used is AMD A10 Processsor and Virtualization is enabled in BIOS (see Task Manager screenshot).

I have checked other posts related to this one and they all say that Virtual Box supports guest OS to be Ubuntu 64 bit, what else do I need to do ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @karel please refer my task manager's screenshot, it says Virtualization "enabled" (after I enabled it in BIOS). Also my host is Windows 8.1.

Comment: @Karel AMD A10-4600M APU supports AMD-V Virtulization (check www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-A-Series-A10-4600M-Notebook-Processor.74065.0.html). Also the BIOS setting is enabled for Virtualization.

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/680051/virtualbox-not-recognizing-64-bit-cpu) suggests Hyper-V might interfere. If you're running Hyper-V, try disabling it.

Comment: Did you download the 64bit version of ubuntu? and not the 32bit version?

Answer (score 1):

Found that Hyper-V needs to be disabled/uninstalled. You can disable Hyper-V without uninstalling it. Start a command prompt with administrator rights and execute the following command:

```
// to disable hyper-v
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

// to enable hyper-v
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Both Operations require restarting your computer.

So once you disable Hyper-V and restart, 64 versions start coming in the list.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are met:

You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see Section 10.3, “Hardware vs. software virtualization”).

You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.

If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.

On 64-bit hosts (which typically come with hardware virtualization support), 64-bit guest operating systems are always supported regardless of settings, so you can simply install a 64-bit operating system in the guest.

Warning

On any host, you should enable the I/O APIC for virtual machines that you intend to use in 64-bit mode. This is especially true for 64-bit Windows VMs. See Section 3.3.2, “"Advanced" tab”. In addition, for 64-bit Windows guests, you should make sure that the VM uses the Intel networking device, since there is no 64-bit driver support for the AMD PCNet card; see Section 6.1, “Virtual networking hardware”.

If you use the "Create VM" wizard of the VirtualBox graphical user interface (see Section 1.7, “Creating your first virtual machine”), VirtualBox will automatically use the correct settings for each selected 64-bit operating system type.
[Source](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)